# XTAL resonance increase the voltage

Tags: crystal

I have a 4Mhz crystal and i connect it in series between the function generator and the oscilloscope probe as shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fysnsa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However i don't know if this testing method for XTAL is true or not but to see if the crystal works or not i set the function generator on 5Vpp and start to increasing the frequency, i was expected to see some change in the output in 4Mhz, but just when the frequency reach 4MHz i find the voltage in the output become 50Vpp !

I know the resonance causes increasing the voltage but there are no Inductor in this case,

So i'm wondering why this happen without inductor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is effectively an inductance, caused by the mechanical arrangement of the piezelectric crystal, called the "[motional inductance](https://www.4timing.com/techcrystal.htm)".

Here is an LTspice model of a 4MHz crystal using values for an ECS 4.000MHz crystal.

[image]

I have simulated your probe with a 10M\$\Omega\$ resistor in parallel with 3pF. Crystal parameters from [this](http://k8iqy.com/miscellaneous/XtalParms/xtal_parameters.htm) page.

The resulting Bode plot is here:

[image]

The peak output is about +30.6dB at the resonance, which is even more than you are seeing.